# Unable to access WebGL app as Azure Web App

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, webgl

I'm trying to deploy a Unity WebGL app to Azure to run as a Web App. But I cannot get the app to deploy. I am using the latest version of Unity (`2022.1.3f1`).

I have built the app, and here are the contents of my `Build`` directory:

```
#  Build> ll
-rw-r--r--  1 DKS0510862  staff  3664517 Jun  9 11:12 DSG Westy Unity PoC.data.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 DKS0510862  staff    78822 Jun  9 11:14 DSG Westy Unity PoC.framework.js.gz
-rw-r--r--@ 1 DKS0510862  staff    20484 Jun  9 11:09 DSG Westy Unity PoC.loader.js
-rw-r--r--  1 DKS0510862  staff  7390463 Jun  9 11:14 DSG Westy Unity PoC.wasm.gz
```

In VS Code, I am navigating to the `Build` directory, right-clicking on the directory, and then selecting `Deploy to Web App`. I am logged in to Azure, and I am prompted to select the App Service that I created in Azure, so my connection is okay.

The deployment seems to have run successfully.

```
4:02:14 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Starting deployment...
4:02:18 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Creating zip package...
4:02:22 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Zip package size: 10.9 MB
4:02:24 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Updating submodules.
4:02:24 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Preparing deployment for commit id '38620705e7'.
4:02:24 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Generating deployment script.
4:02:24 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.
4:02:26 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Generating deployment script for Web Site
4:02:27 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Generated deployment script files
4:02:27 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Running deployment command...
4:02:27 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Command: "C:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Handling Basic Web Site deployment.
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Creating app_offline.htm
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: KuduSync.NET from: 'C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted' to: 'C:\home\site\wwwroot'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Deleting file: 'hostingstart.html'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Copying file: 'DSG Westy Unity PoC.data.gz'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Copying file: 'DSG Westy Unity PoC.framework.js.gz'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Copying file: 'DSG Westy Unity PoC.loader.js'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Copying file: 'DSG Westy Unity PoC.wasm.gz'
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Deleting app_offline.htm
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Finished successfully.
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Running post deployment command(s)...
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
4:02:30 PM innovation-unity-poc-dev: Deployment successful.
4:03:18 PM: Deployment to "innovation-unity-poc-dev" completed.
```

However, when I try to connect to the app, in the browser I am seeing the error message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

I see the following in the Web Server logs, but these don't appear to be error messages.

```
022-06-09 20:08:09 ~1INNOVATION-UNITY-POC-DEV GET /api/logstream/http X-ARR-LOG-ID=bba7b8a4-5d1e-4616-8f43-5237acd8a969 443 - 199.30.194.254 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_15_7)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/102.0.5005.61+Safari/537.36 - - innovation-unity-poc-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 64 2729 1541 180037
2022-06-09 20:08:20 INNOVATION-UNITY-POC-DEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=628fa657-ed76-4252-a55d-c15b3f4150cf 443 - 199.30.194.254 Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_15_7)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/102.0.5005.61+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=22a7daa836b64a8ce56c907737553d08297ff2e76cd06a1f52c29956b9a85c17;+ARRAffinitySameSite=22a7daa836b64a8ce56c907737553d08297ff2e76cd06a1f52c29956b9a85c17 - innovation-unity-poc-dev.azurewebsites.net 403 14 0 422 1626 62
```

The only entry I am seeing in the Application Logs is a request to the logstream API.

I have no idea where to look to do any more troubleshooting. Is there some way I can see what the filesystem looks like for the app, to see if my files were deployed correctly?

Comment: There should be more than 4 files. There should be a html page and 2 folders

Comment: I was only showing the filesystem in the Build folder. The project itself has all the files you mentioned, but the instructions are to deploy it from the Build folder, and that is the only location where the "Deploy to Web App" menu item appears when I right-click.

Comment: I think you’re confused. The top folder where the html is is the build folder. There is then a build folder underneath that.

Comment: Right. But the "Deploy to Web App" only shows up in the right-click menu for the "Build" subfolder. If I right-click on the project at the top level, which contains "index.html", the deploy option is not in. the menu.

Comment: You shouldn’t have built into the top folder of your project. It should have been either outside or a sub folder. 

Haven’t seen deploy to web app outside visual studio. So can’t comment on that one - most people just copy the files and folders

Comment: Thanks for the info, BugFinder! I copied all of those other files into the Build subdirectory, and did another deploy. Now I get the "index.html" file displayed, but only that. It seems like it is not unzipping the other files.